# Errors when installing ROS

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, ros

I followed the ROS official installation document for Mac, and when I came to the step of Resolving Dependencies, it occurred an error saying "Failed to build pygraphviz". Information on the screen is below:

```
Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
  Running setup.py clean for pygraphviz
Failed to build pygraphviz
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
  Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-KKFcFY/pygraphviz/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xRCOPn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    Trying pkg-config
    Package libcgraph was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'libcgraph.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libcgraph' found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-KKFcFY/pygraphviz/setup.py", line 87, in <module>
        tests_require=['nose>=0.10.1', 'doctest-ignore-unicode>=0.1.0',],
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-KKFcFY/pygraphviz/setup_commands.py", line 44, in modified_run
        self.include_path, self.library_path = get_graphviz_dirs()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-KKFcFY/pygraphviz/setup_extra.py", line 121, in get_graphviz_dirs
        include_dirs, library_dirs = _pkg_config()
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-KKFcFY/pygraphviz/setup_extra.py", line 44, in _pkg_config
        output = S.check_output(['pkg-config', '--libs-only-L', 'libcgraph'])
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', '--libs-only-L', 'libcgraph']' returned non-zero exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-KKFcFY/pygraphviz/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xRCOPn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-KKFcFY/pygraphviz
```

How can I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, maybe you need to install the package `libcgraph`.

In Ubuntu, try:

```
apt-cache search libcgraph
```

The output is:

```
libcgraph6 - rich set of graph drawing tools - cgraph library
```

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libcgraph6
```

On Mac, maybe you need to find the same package and install it.
Hope it works.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your reply looks like a comment rather than an answer as OP question is on OSX. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). If you intended to Answer, read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to follow the SO guidelines.